# making windows install with WINUSB on live usb system

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, live-environment

I am trying to make a windowsXP install usb with winusb.  I get a winusb exit code 256.  This error occurs whether i format the drive fat32 or ntfs.  Ive tried the created usb and grub seems to load but bootmgr is missing.....

I have tried running winusb on a live usb, and persistent usb - both end with exit code 256.  I suspect that winusb can only be run on linux IF linux is fully installed on the local harddrive - hence forcing a workaround for usb mounted systems (live/persistent usbs)

The THEORY behind this logic is something i remember reading about live usbs needing to be mounted looped a second time to successfully burn certain mbrs.
Thank you to anyone with live usb experience who has encountered this problem before.

The exact error is:

> Installation failed !
>
> Exit code: 256
>
> Log:
>
> Formating device...
>
> Mounting...
>
> mount: block device /media/7CBAA4537758FCA2/SAVE/DeesBootCD_SlipStreamed2/slip.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
>
> Copying...
>
> Installing grub...
>
> Installation finished. No error reported.
>
> Installing grub.cfg...
>
> Exiting...
>
> Syncing...
>   /usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 15105 Terminated              while true; do
>       sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
>   done
>   Cleaning...
>   /usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 31090 Terminated              while true; do
>       sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
>   done
>   Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_iso_1437887058_25976'...
>   Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_target_1437887058_25976'...